# parsing google 1gram using regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I would like to parse google's 1gram corpus using regular expression, after splitting at newline token `\n` we see the following:

```
'dim\t543950'
'dim\t940'
'dim\t2109'
'dim\t2541373'
'dim .\t1354'
'dim\t598'
'dim\t702'
```

I would like to match all of the above, but not something like:

```
'dim.log\t133'
`dimwit\t133`
```

My current regular expression is:

```
r = re.compile('dim[\s]+')
```

And it seems to work fine when parsing each of the above strings. However, if I now split on `\t` and match with r, most of them are rejected, this makes sense since there is no space after `dim`. Using something like:

```
re.compile(r'dim\b')
```

also does not catch all the ones I need. What is the appropriate regex to match the above cases?

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
^dim( \. )?(\\)?t[0-9]+$
```

regex catches strings only from the group which you've mentioned.